# Is the Pacific Plate composed of smaller plates?

Tags: geology, plate-tectonics, volcanology, tectonics, mantle-plumes

The question, [Why are all lower mantle plumes under oceans?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25640/why-are-all-lower-mantle-plumes-under-oceans) has the following diagram

[image]

which was taken from [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CourtHotspots.png).

About half of the large red dots occur on or near the boundaries of tectonic plates. Two others occur within the Pacific Plate: Hawaii and Caroline. Additionally, there are four yellow hot spots in the Pacific: Macdonald, Tahiti, Pitcairn and Marquesas.

Based on this, is the Pacific Plate one large continuous plate or is it composed of a number of smaller plates?

Comment: the criteria used in that paper are pretty awful, its basically impossible for a continental hotspot to fit their horrible criteria for deep origin. it is unreasonable to expect a hotspot melting through  continental crust to behave the same as once only melting through thin oceanic crust. Its a bit like saying lighting strikes always cause forest fires so lighting only ever strikes forests based on forest fire occurrence. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0012821X15007141